# Tramp connection through proxy

Tags: tramp, proxy

Our servers are behind a proxy that requires two factor authenticatio. I managed to get through the authentication process yet was wondering, is there a way of authenticating only once and not for each different connection?

Answer (score 1):

Tramp could cache passwords. See variable `password-cache-expiry`. Its default value expires cached passwords after 16 seconds.

And/or configure `auth-source.el` properly. For example, add respective entries to `.authinfo`.

Read the Tramp manual, section "Password handling", for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer though I'm not sure either of those solutions can solve the issue. The two factor authentication password keep changes on a constant interval period of time therefore saving the password doesn't really helps in this case. I tried it.

Comment: Then I need your use case. Do you mean that there is the same password for different targets, you would like to reuse?

Comment: all hosts are behind a single proxy server. In order to login to that server and then multi-hop to the other hosts I must to enter a password that keeps on changing each minute. Thats why saving this password wouldn't help. Is there a way of reusing the connection with the proxy server when connecting to different hosts?

Comment: I cannot say it for sure. But if `tramp-use-ssh-controlmaster-options` is set to t, and `tramp-ssh-controlmaster-options` is set to something like `"-o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%%C' -o ControlPersist=no"`, it could work. Both variables exist since Emacs 24.1, I believe.

Comment: Thanks again, I tried to use the config you suggested and noticed that this issue only happen when I use the 'sudo' method. If I connect without it it works great and doesn't prompt me for a password login on each connection.

Comment: Yes, for the `sudo` method there doesn't exist connection reusing.